# Автоматическое заполнение полей при редактировании объекта в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

За основу взял вот этот [код](https://github.com/java-course-ee/java-course-ee/blob/master/Spring/MVC/GS_Spring_005/src/main/java/ru/expomap/test/controller/TasksController.java).

В чём моя проблема - при редактировании любого уже созданного объекта - автоматически не заполняются поля. С примером же на гитхабе всё в порядке - поля заполняются.

Далее мой код:

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "rating", catalog = "school")
public class Rating {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ratingId", unique = true, nullable = false)
int rt_id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
@Column(name = "ratingDate", nullable = false)
Date rt_Date;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "chId", nullable = false)
Children children;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "subjectId", nullable = false)
Subject subject;

@Column(name = "evaluation", nullable = false)
int evaluation;
*сеттеры, геттеры и конструктор без параметров*
```

**Контроллер (пока такой):**

```
@Controller
public class RatingController {

    private SubjectService subjectService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setSubjectService(SubjectService subjectService) {
        this.subjectService = subjectService;
    }


    private RatingService ratingService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setRatingService(RatingService ratingService) {
        this.ratingService = ratingService;
    }


    private ChildrenService childrenService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void setChildrenService(ChildrenService childrenService) {
        this.childrenService = childrenService;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("subjects")
    public List<Subject> getAllSubjects() {
        return subjectService.listSubjects();
    }


    @ModelAttribute("childrens")
    public List<Children> getAllChildrens() {
        return childrenService.listChildrens();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("listRatings")
    public List<Rating> getAllRatings() {
        return this.ratingService.listRatings();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "ratings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listRatings(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("rating", new Rating());
        return "ratings";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ratings/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRating(@ModelAttribute("rating") Rating rating) {

        if (rating.getRt_id() == 0) {
            this.ratingService.addRating(rating);
        }else {
            this.ratingService.updateRating(rating);
        }
        return "redirect:/ratings";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/ratings/edit/{id}")
    public String updateRating(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        Rating rating = (Rating) this.ratingService.getRatingById(id);
        model.addAttribute("rating", rating);
        return "ratings";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/ratings/delete/{id}")
    public String removeRating(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        this.ratingService.removeRating(id);
        return "redirect:/ratings";
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Children.class, "children", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            public void setAsText(String text) {
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(text);
                Children children = (Children) childrenService.getChildrenById(id);
                setValue(children);

            }

            public String getAsText() {
                Object value = getValue();
                if (value != null) {
                    Children children = (Children) value;

                    return children.getCh_name();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });



        binder.registerCustomEditor(Subject.class, "subject", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
            public void setAsText(String text) {
                Integer sub_id = Integer.parseInt(text);
                Subject subject = (Subject) subjectService.getSubjectById(sub_id);
                setValue(subject);

            }

            public String getAsText() {
                Object value = getValue();
                if (value != null) {
                    Subject subject = (Subject) value;

                    return subject.getSub_name();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });

    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                dateFormat, true));
    }
}
```

**И JSP:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Список оценок</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Список оценок</h1>
<c:if test="${!empty listRatings}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width = "80">ID</th>
            <th width = "120">Дата</th>
            <th width = "120">Ученик</th>
            <th width = "120">Предмет</th>
            <th width = "120">Оценка</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listRatings}" var="rating">
            <tr>
                <th>${rating.rt_id}</th>
                <th><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${rating.rt_Date}" /></th>
                <th>${rating.children.ch_name}&nbsp ${rating.children.ch_surname}</th>
                <th>${rating.subject.sub_name}</th>
                <th>${rating.evaluation}</th>
                <td width = "120"><a href="<c:url value="/ratings/edit/${rating.rt_id}"/>">Редактировать</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/ratings/delete/${rating.rt_id}"/>">Удалить</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>


<h1>Добавить оценку</h1>
<c:url var="addAction" value="/ratings/add"/>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="rating">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty rating.rt_id}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="rt_id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="rt_id" readonly="true"  disabled="true"/>
                    <form:hidden path="rt_id"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="rt_Date">
                    <spring:message text="Дата оценки"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="rt_Date"  placeholder="День/Месяц/Год"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Учащийся</td>
            <td><form:select path="children" items="${childrens}" 
            itemLabel="ch_name" itemValue="ch_id"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="children"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Предмет</td>
            <td><form:select path="subject" items="${subjects}" selected="true"
                             itemLabel="sub_name"
                             itemValue="sub_id"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="subject" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="evaluation">
                <spring:message text="Оценка"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="evaluation">
                <option value="0">Отсутствовал</option>
                <option value="1">Присутствовал</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <c:if test="${!empty rating.rt_Date}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Edit Rating"/>"/>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${empty rating.rt_Date}">
                    <input type="submit"
                           value="<spring:message text="Add Rating"/>"/>
                </c:if>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Пример]
Что я упустил в понимании данного механизма (автозаполнение формы при редактировании)? Спасибо!

Comment: Какие поля у Вас не выводятся, и какие выводятся?

Comment: Я сверху привёл ссылку на git, в которой если нажать "редактировать" (объект Task), то этот объект Task сначала как - бы уже заполнил все свои поля и мне не нужно их снова "выбирать/вбивать" (ведь я, возможно, хотел изменить лишь одно поле, предположим). У меня же такого невыходит, в скриншоте, что Вы видите я нажал на "Джоли" редактировать - но автоматически заполнилось только время, а остальные поля (являющиеся объектами) "не выбрались " автоматически и их нужно заполнять все заново. Видимо я что-то не понял? Спасибо.

Comment: Я хотел у Вас уточнить, при нажатии на редактировать, поле ID заполнено правильной ID, и при этом другие поля не заполнены?

Comment: Да, ID и Дата верны, остальное (всё что нужно выбирать из списков) неверно.

Comment: Проверьте свой метод `this.ratingService.getRatingById(id);`, действительно ли он возвращает нужные Вам данные с прогруженными сущностями `subject` и `children` (Вывести в консоль). Поле `evaluation` я бы переделелал добавлением его значений в контроллер, как и `subject`.

Comment: Я попробовал вывести после `getRatingById(id)`  в DAO и в Controller'е `rating.getChildren().getCh_id()` - вроде бы id возвращается правильный и все поля присутствуют. Вы это имели в виду? А по поводу evaluation - это пока временно, не придумал что-то лучшее))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном проекте на гитхабе используется `initBinder`, который подставляет нужное значение в поле. Можно его использовать и в дальнейшем.

Для правильного отображения `form:select` нужно указывать не `path="subject"`, а `path="subject.sub_id"`, т.е. id, которое будет вставлено в `itemValue="sub_id"`. Пример кода:

```
<h1>Добавить оценку</h1>
<form:form action="test" commandName="rating">
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
            ID
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="rt_id" readonly="true"  disabled="true"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          subject.sub_name
      </td>
      <td>
          <form:input path="subject.sub_name" readonly="true"  disabled="true"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Предмет</td>
      <td><form:select path="subject.sub_id" items="${subjects}"
                       itemLabel="sub_name"
                       itemValue="sub_id"/>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form:form>
```

В контроллере:

```
@RequestMapping("/rating")
public String updateRating( Model model) {

    Rating rating = new Rating();
    rating.setRt_id(1);

    Subject subject = new Subject();
    subject.setSub_id(3);
    subject.setSub_name("CCCC");
    rating.setSubject(subject);

    model.addAttribute("rating", rating);
    return "test";
}

@ModelAttribute("subjects")
public List<Subject> getAllSubjects() {

    List<Subject>subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();

    Subject subject = new  Subject();
    subject.setSub_id(1);
    subject.setSub_name("AAAA");
    subjects.add(subject);

    subject = new Subject();
    subject.setSub_id(2);
    subject.setSub_name("BBBB");
    subjects.add(subject);

    subject = new Subject();
    subject.setSub_id(3);
    subject.setSub_name("CCCC");
    subjects.add(subject);

    return subjects;
}



class Subject {
    private int sub_id;
    private String sub_name;
    //get,set
}


class Rating {
    private int rt_id;
    private Subject subject;
    //get,set
}
```

Comment: Сразу же заработало!  Огромное спасибо за потраченое время и решение проблемы! Удачи!